# how browser get our id and password

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jsp

When ever we are login in any website threw login form then our browser ask to us do you want to "Remember Password" and if we give yes then it save our id with password.

can any one explain me how any browser get our id and password from that fields?

Answer (score 2):

When done correctly, your username and password isn't saved, but a cookie containing a randomly generated ID is.  When you visit that site again, your browser sends the cookie that the server had originally given it, along with its request for the page.  The server gets this cookie and logs you in.

If you are referring to the built-in browser functionality, a browser just keeps a database on your hard drive of usernames/passwords for certain sites.